# Automatically appending post title into post content upon publishing of post?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, append, title

Please tell me, how can I fetch the post title and append it into the content of that post when I click the publish button?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The [`wp_insert_post_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) filter allows you to manipulate the post data before it is inserted in the database:

```
function so16876611_insert_post_data( $data , $postarr )
{
    $data['post_content'] = $data['post_content'] . $data['post_title'];
    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'so16876611_insert_post_data', 99, 2 );
```

Comment: Isn't post content stored under 'content' key ? I mean $data['content']

Comment: nope, check the params: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data

Answer (score 1):

You would need to access save_post hook that's being triggered after creating/updating page. It would look something like below:

```
function custom_save_post($post_id) 
{
    $_POST['content']=  $_POST['post_name'].$_POST['content']; 
}
add_action("save_post", "custom_save_post");
```